# Prevent method from running when using @EventListener(ApplicationReadyEvent.class) during testing

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I have the following test class in my project

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
public class AddressParserTest {

    @Test
    public void parseAddressTest() {
        try {
          // my code
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

and I have some methods in my project that are annotated with `@EventListener(ApplicationReadyEvent.class)` which run after Spring Boot starts up

```
@Component
public class MyClass {

    @EventListener(ApplicationReadyEvent.class)
    public void myMethod() {
       //my code
    }
}
```

When I run the `AddressParserTest` the `myMethod` method also runs because of the `@EventListener(ApplicationReadyEvent.class)` is there anyway to prevent it from running during testing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use profiles in this situation.

- Annotate your class with `@Profile` (please note the "!" in front of "test". This means: load this class, only if the profile is not "test")

```
@Component
@Profile("!test")
public class MyClass {

    @EventListener(ApplicationReadyEvent.class)
    public void myMethod() {
       //my code
    }
}
```

- Annotate your test class with `@ActiveProfiles("test")`

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
@ActiveProfiles("test")
public class AddressParserTest {

    @Test
    public void parseAddressTest() {
        try {
          // my code
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

Hope it helps !